# onClick/onSelected Event of a button in a GWT CellList

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT CellList. Each Cell has one image, two label, and one button.

Whenever user click a Cell, onSelected event occures.

I want to fire onClick event if user click on a button,
onSelected if click other area(not inside button).

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to override `onBrowserEvent(...)` method of `AbstractCell<C>`. Here is how i implemented it to deal with click events on a `<a/>` element:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, BIBonusDto value, NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<BIBonusDto> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
        if (!Element.is(eventTarget)) {
            return;
        }
        if (parent.getElementsByTagName("a").getItem(0).isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
            if (valueUpdater != null)
                valueUpdater.update(value);
        }
    }
}
```

the cell template looks like this:

```
<div id='info' class='campaign' style='cursor:default;'>
  <div id='claim-inner2'>
    <a id='claim-inner1' style='cursor:pointer;'>
      <div id='claim-inner' title='Claim Points Now'></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

We have to check if the event is of the right type and if it's an element, then we can check if it's the right one and delegate the action to a value updater callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

You can either have ActionCell or ButtonCell.

Let me know if this serve your purpose or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry too late reply you. Your suggestion is good but it does not what I want.

I want to customise CellList. I want, inside a member of a CellList, separating focus of button and other area.